# Writing a group as a product of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, cyclic-groups

How do I go about expressing a group as a product of cyclic groups? For example, express:

$$O^*_K = \{\pm (24 + 5\sqrt{23})^r : r\in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

as a product of cyclic groups ($O^*_K$ is the group of units in $O_K = \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{23} ]$). I was given that the answer is: $$ \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z} $$

Could you please explain this in a general way so that I can do the same for any group:

$$O^*_K =  \{\pm (a + b\sqrt{d})^r : r\in \mathbb{Z} \} \quad d>0$$

Thank you.

Comment: Um, what kind of answer do you expect? Any group of the form $\{\pm z^r\mid r\in \mathbb Z\}$ for a fixed complex number $z$ that is not a root of unity will be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Exactly, the answer was already there. As to why it can be written like that: it's Dirichlet's unit theorem.